# Configure a custom SSLSocketFactory for an administered connection factory object?

Tags: java, ssl, jms, websphere, ibm-mq

Here is my setup:

Client: MDB listener running on WebSphere Application Server (version 8.5)
Server: WebSphere MQ Queue Manager (version 7.5) running on a different machine.

The listener connects to the queue manager using a JMS queue connection factory configuration. The connection details such as host name, port, queue manager name, etc… are stored in an external LDAP repository as an administered connection factory object. The WebSphere does a JNDI retrieval of the administered object using its name, and then makes the actual connection.

Now I have a requirement to secure the connection using SSL. Further, I have to create a custom SSLSocketFactory object using self-created keyStore and trustStore files, and set it in the connection factory object. In a standalone java client it looks something like this:

```
MQQueueConnectionFactory queueConnectionFactorySecure = (MQQueueConnectionFactory) initialDirContext.lookup(jndiQueueConnectionFactorySecure);
SSLSocketFactory sslSocketFactory = getCustomSocketFactory(keystoreFile, truststoreFile, keystorePassword, truststorePassword);
queueConnectionFactorySecure.setSSLSocketFactory(sslSocketFactory);
```

I have to do something similar for the MDB listener. I tried exploring WebSphere Administration Console, but no luck. Of course, I can choose the “WebSphere MQ Provider”, supply the host name, port, etc… directly, but that spoils the whole purpose of maintaining a central administered objects repository.

Has anyone done something like this? Any idea if it is possible to do at all? I could not find any conclusive answers through my numerous searches on this topic.

Comment: I would first ask why? Why do you think you have to use a 'self-created' keystore and truststore? Why can't you use the system in the normal way?

Comment: In my case I need a private key to authenticate the MQ client. If I set keystore for the whole JVM I cannot connect to an other type of service I need. And I don´t like passwords in JVM parameters. So I really search for a way to combine JNDI for MQ and a custom SSLContext.